# How to install Subrion on Windows Xampp when this error pops up

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
>   will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\classes\ia.core.mysql.php on line 58
>
> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'lexhost'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\classes\ia.core.mysql.php on line 58 Could
>   not connect.

Is there any way to use **mysqli or PDO** for this?

Comment: Please send us your codes

Comment: This seems to be a warning. (For installation questions probably SO is not the proper site.) [ask]

Comment: Is your db username and password correctly given ?

Comment: Hi, this issue is fixed in the latest version of Subrion CMS. The issue is that you were trying to install it on PHP 5.5 and MySQL adapter for it is obsolete. Now it uses MySQLi by default so there should not be any issues. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The access denied warning is a basic database connection error (user, password or database is wrong). You can directly edit `/includes/config.inc.php` to fix your database credentials. (You may need to go into phpmyadmin to confirm settings match also.)

To fix the deprecation warning, in that same config file change:

```
define('INTELLI_CONNECT', 'mysql');
```

To:

```
define('INTELLI_CONNECT', 'mysqli');
```

That will get rid of the mysql deprecated warnings and be more secure.

Comment: Thanks. You're absolutely correct about this.Anyhow, it didn't affect installation process though as installation had its own methods with mysql adapter. We have this fixed in the latest version of Subrion CMS. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys I figured out my mistake (Noob). I did not create the databases before registering Db-name, user & password, Sorry for the hassle. Thanks again